# fork - parent child program

Tags: c, fork

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h
#include<unistd.h>
int value=5;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
pid_t pid;
pid=fork();
if(pid==0)
{
value+=15;
}
else if(pid>0)
{
wait(NULL);
printf("Parent value:=%d",value);
exit(0);
}
return 0;
}
```

What is the output of this program?
Can the value of parent be 20 or the child will av its own copy of the variable "Value"

Comment: @sixlettervariables It's not the same question; the referenced question is about pthreads, where the answer is different from the answer for this question.  (Granted, they are closely related, but it isn't the same.)

Comment: @Lasse: that is over-aggressive and inaccurate moderating.  It is not the same question!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: that's my bad, I actually read them as identical, I'll refrain from voting to close while switching off night shift.

Comment: Ok, I'll reopen and reclose then.

Comment: OK; I'll go with "it isn't a very good question", though it isn't a very bad question either.

Answer (score 1):

Parent will have its own copy of the variable "value" and so the output would be 5

> Did you try executing this above code?